# Multiplying two series with wildcards in graphite

Tags: data-visualization, metrics, graphite

I'm looking to optimize some pages in my web app by using graphite to identify bottlenecks.

My rough formula is something like `weight = number_of_requests * response_time`.

I have something like this at the moment - the first wildcard represents controller, and the second represents the action:

```
highestMax(
  multiplySeries(
    response_time.*.*.75percentile, 
    summarize(request.*.*.count, "1hour", "avg")
  ) 
5)
```

This doesn't work, I'm assuming because of the wildcards.

I tried to do some nested `groupByNode` magic, but that didn't seem to work either (how do I pass the value of the node to the callback in the second `groupByNode`?).

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time on this as well and eventually implemented multiplySeriesWithWildcards. See if it will fit your requirement. I sent a pull request for my change 
https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/pull/634